# WPF Reuse DataGrid TemplateColumn DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I've build a datagrid which has a custom column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn 
    Header="{x:Static local:MainWindowResources.gasNameLabel}" 
    Width="*" 
    MinWidth="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox 
                Name="GasNameTextBox" 
                Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                Padding="2,0,0,0" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger 
                    SourceName="GasNameTextBox" 
                    Property="IsVisible" 
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter 
                        TargetName="GasNameTextBox" 
                        Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" 
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=GasNameTextBox}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label 
                Name="GasNameLabel" 
                Content="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                Padding="0,0,0,0" 
                Margin="6,2,2,2" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As I am going to be reusing such column definition A LOT, I would really like to define it as an external DataTemplate to which I only provide the property to bind on (Binding Path= ...) and that the rest is reused...that way I would define Text template, Checkbox template and such and reuse them in various grids and only change bindings to different properties.

Is that possible?

Vladan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849460/how-to-reuse-wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-including-binding

Answer (score 0):

Use a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) instead, put that in your application resources, and reuse the usercontrol.